# How do I inflate dialog at the bottom of my layout?

Tags: java, android

My swipe to dismiss dialog is currently showing at the center of my layout which matches the parent's width. No left/right margins. I want to place it on the bottom.

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_fmcg_popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      // other code goes here

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code for swipe to dismiss dialog. I am currently using a swipe to dismiss dialog library.

```
 View dialog = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_fmcg_popup, null);
                        TextView tvfmcg2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_fmcg2);
                        tvfmcg2.setText(message);
                        swipeDismissDialog = new SwipeDismissDialog.Builder(this)
                                .setView(dialog)
                                .setOnSwipeDismissListener(new OnSwipeDismissListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSwipeDismiss(View view, SwipeDismissDirection direction) {
                                        Preferences.setString(Prefkey.last_qualified_fmcg_voucher_on_remove, message);
                                    }
                                })
                                .setFlingVelocity(0)
                                .setOverlayColor(0)
                                .build()
                                .show();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code this will show the dialog at the bottom of the screen:

```
  Dialog dialog
    //code to initialize dialog here

    Window window = dlg.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

    wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

Comment: I am using a View. That code is not workingn since it's for dialog, I guess.

Comment: swipeDismissDialog is a dialog I guess? you can pass swipeDismissDialog object.